# How to load a page when item is selected using Keyboard navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this keyboard navigation on my website.

I am trying to load a different html file when it is selected.

For example when item 1 is selected, `item1.html` is loaded. When item 2 is selected, `item2.html` is loaded. How do I use the JavaScript.

I cannot find any references online.

```js
(function($, document) {
    'use strict';

    var items = $('#list').children();

    function selectItem(item) {
        item.addClass('selected')
            .attr('aria-selected', 'true')
            .siblings()
            .removeClass('selected')
            .attr('aria-selected', 'false');
    }

    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        var key = event.which,
            direction = null,
            position = null,
            item  = null;

        switch (key) {
            case 35: // End
                position = 'last';
                break;
            case 36: // Home
                position = 'first';
                break;
            case 38: // Key up
                direction = 'prev';
                break;
            case 40: // Key down
                direction = 'next';
                break;
        }

        if (position) {
            item = items[position]();
        } else if (direction) {
            item = items.filter('.selected')[direction]();
        }

        if (item) {
            selectItem(item);
        }
    });

    $('#list a').click(function() {
        selectItem($(this).closest('li'));
        return false;
    });

    selectItem(items.first());

})(jQuery, document);
```

```css
body {
    width: 30em;
    margin: 2em auto;
    font: 81.25%/1.5 Lato, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    color: #444;
    background-color: #fff;
}

kbd {
    padding: 2px 3px;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#list {
    width: 12em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

#list a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 3;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #393;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

#list li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#list li.selected a {
    background-color: #c22;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main role="main">
    <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>

    <p>Click on this demo to give it focus.</p>
    <p>Click to select an item or use <kbd>key up</kbd>, <kbd>key down</kbd>, <kbd>home</kbd>, or <kbd>end</kbd>.</p>
</main>
```

Any help or links to explanations would be great. Thank you!

Comment: do you want to reload the page when you select an item?

Comment: Sorry, I think I didnt mention properly. I added another ENTER button, when the ITEM its selected and I press ENTER the page is loaded. For example when item 1 is selected, item1.html is loaded when I press ENTER. When item 2 is selected, item2.html is loaded when I press ENTER.

Comment: Its ok if the page is reloaded. @sidd

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with jquery on click function

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <main role="main">
        <ul id="list">
            <li id="Item1"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
            <li id="Item2"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
            <li id="Item3"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>

        </ul>

        <p>Click on this demo to give it focus.</p>
        <p>Click to select an item or use <kbd>key up</kbd>, <kbd>key down</kbd>, <kbd>home</kbd>, or <kbd>end</kbd>.</p>
    </main>
    <div id="demo"></div>
```

**jquery function**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#Item1").on('click',function(){
        $('#demo').load('Item1.html');
        }
    });
    $("#Item2").on('click',function(){
        $('#demo').load('Item2.html');
        }
    });
    $("#Item3").on('click',function(){
        $('#demo').load('Item3.html');
        }
    });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I didnt mention properly. I added another ENTER button, when the ITEM its selected and I press ENTER the page is loaded. For example when item 1 is selected, item1.html is loaded when I press ENTER. When item 2 is selected, item2.html is loaded when I press ENTER.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event handler on the window that listens to enter key up and opens the page which is selected something like this

```
window.addEventListener("keyup",function(evt){
    if(evt.keyCode == 13){  // 13 is for enter
        // get the selected index here and then pass it like this
        window.location.href="yourDesiredLink.com/yourDesiredPage.html"
    }
})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: this works, but what i mean is, it loads the html I wanted when I select(or click enter) and the ITEMs.Thanks for helping @sidd

Comment: If this worked for you please select it as an answer.

Thanks

Comment: What I mean is actually it loads item1.html when I click ENTER while Item 1 is selected. It loads item2.html when I click ENTER while Item 2 is selected.How do I use the JavaScript.